# using rail_some_route_path(nil) renders 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Say we had a route:

```
get "foo/:foo_param" =>"blahblah" , :as=>"rails_some_route"
```

and in my views I write:

```
"rails_some_route_path('aa')" this give proper url => 'foo/aa'
```

But if a view(another .slim file) accidently contains
`"a href=#{rails_some_route_path(nil)}"` .
the view itself renders as 404 .

Only route should be broken , but strangely the page itself renders 404

`consider_all_requests_local` is false for dev

Application controller

```
unless config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, :with => :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, :with => :render_404
    rescue_from Error404, :with => :render_404
    rescue_from GoshPosh::Platform::Errors::AuthError do
      redirect_to login_path({:rd=>request.path})
    end
  end
```

routes  :

```
  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    match '*not_found', :to => 'web_application#render_404'
  end
```

Comment: Do you rescue exceptions and display the 404 page in your application controller?

Comment: I added the code that rescues it.. But thats only for production mode